# Overlapping items in CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to do a responsive layout with css grid by getting two elements to overlap each other halfway. On wide screens they are in one row and overlapping horizontally, but on narrow screens they should be in one column and overlap vertically.

Here is an illustration of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Is this behavior possible with css grid? Here is how far I got but now I'm stuck trying to get the vertical overlap.

```css
.wrapper {
  background: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(444px, 1fr));
}

.wrapper__red,
.wrapper__green {
  align-self: center;
}

.wrapper__red {
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
}

.wrapper__green {
  justify-self: end;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1 class="wrapper__red">Title text goes here</h1>
  <img class="wrapper__green" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
</div>
```

Comment: @PacoGómezCapón I needed to do it with css grid for flexibility to authors in a CMS. However the thought of media queries lead me to an acceptable solution for now.

Comment: I’s very doable, but you may need to use `z-index`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In CSS Grid you can create overlapping grid areas.

Grid makes this simple and easy with **line-based placement**.

*From the spec:*

> [**8.3. Line-based
>   Placement**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#line-placement)
>
> The `grid-row-start`, `grid-column-start`, `grid-row-end`, and
>   `grid-column-end` properties determine a grid item’s size and location
>   within the grid by contributing a line, a span, or nothing (automatic)
>   to its grid placement, thereby specifying the inline-start,
>   block-start, inline-end, and block-end edges of its grid area.

*note: re-size demo below to transition from desktop to mobile view*

```css
article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

section:nth-child(1) { grid-column: 1 / 4; grid-row: 1; z-index: 1; }
section:nth-child(2) { grid-column: 3 / 5; grid-row: 1; }
section:nth-child(3) { grid-column: 5 / 7; grid-row: 1; }

@media ( max-width: 500px ) {
   article { grid-template-columns: 100px; justify-content: center; }
   section:nth-child(1) { grid-row: 1 / 4; grid-column: 1; }
   section:nth-child(2) { grid-row: 3 / 5; grid-column: 1; }
   section:nth-child(3) { grid-row: 5 / 7; grid-column: 1; }
}

/* non-essential demo styles */
section:nth-child(1) { background-color: lightgreen; }
section:nth-child(2) { background-color: orange; }
section:nth-child(3) { background-color: aqua; }
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <section><span>1</span></section>
  <section><span>2</span></section>
  <section><span>3</span></section>
</article>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pog9bwpq/)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added:

```
section {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

to my grid blocks which gave me blocks the same height regardless of any wrapping or not.

```
<article>
  <section><span>1</span></section>
  <section><span>2</span></section>
  <section><span>3</span></section>
</article>
```