# how to make div overlapped another div using html and css

Tags: html, css, overflow, z-index, dropdown

I have two `div` container, one act as dropdown component, when dropdown clicked, it will not overlapped second component. I am trying using `z-index` and `css` `position`, also it didnt work, try another solution from so and googling but not found the answer, hope anyone can guide this. this is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vco2od?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) I created, what have I tried:

**html**

```
<div>
  <div class="div1" (click)="selectSavedCard()">
    <div *ngIf='!hasSelected'>
      <div>
        <p>dropdown V</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let card of savedCards">
      <div>
        <p>{{card.viewValue}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="show">
    <div *ngFor="let card of savedCreditCards" (click)="selectDropdownCard(card)">
      <div>
        <p>{{card.viewValue}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">overlapped this div</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.div1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
    z-index: 1;
}

.div2 {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

**ts**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361243/overlapping-items-in-css-grid - take a look at the question and the answer. i guess this will help you. with best regards

Comment: link you give state on how to overlapped items on responsive design I think,

Comment: Please update your sample without angular, so it is shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the dropdown of div1 to overlap the div2 right?
There are multiple ways to do this, but the simplest one i can imagine is to simply put a `position: absolute;`
property on the dropdown div.

```
<div>
  <div class="div1" (click)="selectSavedCard()" [(ngModel)]="selectedCard" ngDefaultControl>
    <div *ngIf='!hasSelected'>
      <div>
        <p>dropdown V</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute;z-index: 100;background: #aaa;width: 100%;" *ngFor="let card of savedCards">
      <div>
        <p>{{card.viewValue}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute;z-index: 100;background: #aaa;width: 100%;" *ngIf="show">
    <div *ngFor="let card of savedCreditCards" (click)="selectDropdownCard(card)">
      <div>
        <p>{{card.viewValue}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">overlapped this div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Let me know if this helps

Comment: Maybe that is because of z-index. I have updated the code and provide some more css. Try using those.

Answer (score 0):

From your  [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frxvgg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) link behavior I think you just don't want the overlapped div to be pushed down when the dropdown is clicked.
You just need to add a wrapper around your dropdown and set the position of the dropdown content to be absolute.
I will edit your `stackblitz` app HTML and CSS to show this.

**app.component.html**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<div class="container-div">
  <div class="wrapp-dropdown">
    <div class="div1" (click)="selectSavedCard()" [(ngModel)]="selectedCard" ngDefaultControl>
     <div *ngIf='!hasSelected'>
       <div>
         <p>dropdown V</p>
       </div>
     </div>
    <div *ngFor="let card of savedCards" class="dropdown-content">
    <div>
      <p>{{card.viewValue}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
   <div *ngIf="show" class="dropdown-content">
  <div *ngFor="let card of savedCreditCards" (click)="selectDropdownCard(card)">
      <div>
        <p>{{card.viewValue}}</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="div2">overlapped this div</div>
```

Then I updated your **app.component.css** to look like this

```
p {
   font-family: Lato;
}

.container-div {
   position: relative;
}

.div1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

.wrap-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
}

b.div2 {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: almost done, but i want to overflow 'div2', I think using position: fixed not suitable

Comment: use absolute, that must have been a mistake I made while typing. Let me correct it.