# CSS Grid: Is it possible to change z-index by targeting specific grid-items created dynamically?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to be able to hover over or click a grid cell and have hidden elements(like a footer) display and overlap other grid-items without affecting the overall grid layout.

I know it's possible to overlap cells as in this example-

[Overlapping items in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361243/overlapping-items-in-css-grid)

but as the example shows, the column and row are set beforehand. Is there a way to select a grid-item in order to change it's `z-index` when item is added dynamically?

The grid items are added using auto-fit. I am able to span multiple rows by adding a class like so-

```
$(document).on('click', '.card-footer', function () {
        $(this).closest('.card').toggleClass('row-span');
});
```

```css
    .row-span {
        grid-row: span 2;
        /*z-index: 1; doesn't work*/
        /*footer:nth-child(4) {  z-index: 1; } doesn't work */
    }
```

The html is created dynamically through ajax calls, each image is added to the cards class in a template similar to-

```
</div class="cards">
    <div class="card bg-light" id='${image.id}'>
    <div class="card-header">${image.header}</div>
    <div class="card-body">${image.body}</div>
    <div class="card-footer">${image.footer}</div>
</div>
```

css-

```
.cards {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(125px, .25fr));
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    align-items: start;
    width: 100vw;
    padding-right: 6px;
        }
```

when I add this class to an element I am able to get only that grid-item to span multiple rows but this still affects the other grid items. I don't understand why I am not able to change the `z-index` in order to overlap the other `grid-items`, yet I can change the `grid-row: span value`.

Comment: give your HTML code or provide fiddle.

Comment: can you please create a snippet for your problem?

Comment: I hope the additional code snippets are helpful. I will create a fiddle if I am unable to get a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 3):

> I am able to get only that grid-item to span multiple rows but this still affects the other grid items

This is the default behavior of item placement. The browser will never make element overlap unless you explicitely define this by making two items on the same row/column. Also `z-index` has nothing to do here since it will simply define the stacking order.

If you want to create overlap consider changing the width/height to have an overlow that will not affect the other grid items.

Example:

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill,minmax(150px,1fr));
  grid-auto-rows:50px;
  grid-gap:10px;
}
.container > div {
  border:2px solid; 
}

.row-2 {
  height:calc(200% + 10px); /* Span 2 rows (don't consider the gap)*/
  background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  z-index:2;
}

.column-2 {
  width:calc(200% + 10px); /* Span 2 columns (don't consider the gap)*/
  background:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);
  z-index:2;
}
.row-3 {
  height:calc(300% + 2*10px); /* Span 3 rows (don't consider the gap)*/
  background:rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
  z-index:2;
}

* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column-2"></div>
  <div class="row-2"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="row-3"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think what you're saying is it is not possible using my method. I edited my question to add code snippets explaining all the elements are added dynamically and their positions will always vary.

Comment: @jmoney the way you add the elements and their position is irrelevant. If you want to obtain an overlap and have your element taking 2 rows (or 2 columns) you need to make the width/height bigger and not change grid-row or grid-column

Comment: I added your .row-2 class css to my .row-span class and it did not do anything.

Comment: Okay I am working on your code in a fiddle, I see that it works, so thank you. I don't understand why it's not working on my app though. I'm wondering if there is another class overriding the style. Testing now.

Comment: I made the class selector more specific which helped, although it is still making the row underneath drop down a little bit. It's causing the other elements in that row to gain additional height.

Comment: For some reason the padding is causing the row to increase in height. When I comment the padding out, the row height stays the same. It also stays the same with .card padding set to 1 or 2 px or rem, as soon as I set it to 3 px or .3 rem it causes the jump in height. It's unfortunate because it needs to be .5 rem or 5 px.

Comment: @jmoney show me a working code so I can help you debug

Comment: The padding-left causes the jump at .3em/px/rem, the padding-right at .5em/px/rem. Once the either padding is set to that point the entire row jumps approx 10px in height(not due to your code). I have no clue what could cause this. I can try to recreate as much as possible in a fiddle but it seems pretty daunting.

Comment: tried to copy and paste and I'm not going to be able to recreate it easily. I'll try again when I have a couple hrs just to reproduce the problem. Any suggestions in the meantime?

Comment: @jmoney it's difficult to give suggestions with the code. When you have the code ready let me know. If you have a link to a website it's also ok

Comment: Quick question, is it possible to use height: auto? Would work better in instances where content expands beyond 2 rows. Getting burnt out on the problem. There is a text-nowrap class that gets toggled to expose the text but there is no css for that class! It will overlap when there is no text but the text is pushing the next row down. nvm when I removed the text-nowrap toggle it didn't overlap, although I set the exact height...

Comment: Ok, it only works when the height is calculated. Why is that?

Comment: I have a fiddle here- https://jsfiddle.net/vebd0k3x/ I noticed when I changed the grid-auto-rows: from 50 px to auto, it recreated my issue. So two things, I only set the grid like so grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(125px, .25fr)), so the grid items size is dependent on the number of items. Second, I don't understand how I can overlap when using calc, but any other method will not overlap and additionally I can't get the text to overlap even after removing all css in dev tools, it did overlap before except for a small jump that went away when reducing l/r padding.

Comment: @jmoney it's clear. It cannot work if the height of row/items is auto. The whole idea using percentage and calc is to make the element span twice the height of its row but if the next row doesn't have the same height then it won't work. My trick only work if you define a template row or they have the same height by default

Comment: I understand that but I was able to get it to essentially work minus the slight jump that went away when I reduced the padding. Now I can't get the text to not affect the row height.  I need the calc to be based on the height prior to to the expanded text. Somehow it was doing it before. I'll have to work on it when I'm not so tired. Front end is not enjoyable. Thanks for your help though, it's got me on the right path.

Comment: so I can set the grid-auto-rows: through javascript based on the card height which allows the overlap with expanded text to work without affecting the row height, Unfortunately I'll have to check if text is expanded on every window resize event then reset grid-auto-rows. Hopefully it's not buggy. I still am obsessed with how I was able to expand the text without affecting row height previously as that would be ideal.